# Non-Chen primes dividing $3^k+3$ and $2^k-3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

A non-Chen prime is a prime $p$ such that $p+2$ is neither a prime nor a semi-prime. $3^6+3=732$ is divisibile by the non-Chen prime $61$. On the other hand, $2^6-3=61$.

> Are there infinitely many $k$ such that both $3^k+3$ and $2^k-3$ are divisibile by the same non-Chen prime? Could somebody find another example besides $k=6$ ?

Comment: do you have mathematica? you could search quite quickly for $k$ that work using [FactorInteger](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorInteger.html)

Comment: @Zubin Even with Wolfram Alpha some results could be obtained. Hold on...

Comment: Actually, GCD might be more informative: `Table[GCD[3^n + 3, 2^n - 3], {n, 500}]` In the results you'll see lots of 1s, a few 5s and a few 61s. Of course 1 is not prime and 5 is prime but it's a Chen prime.

Comment: @RobertSoupe yes, it looks like the sequence $$\{a_n\},\,\,\,\, a_n = \gcd\left(3^n+3, 2^n-3\right)$$ is repeating with period $60$.

Comment: @Zubin Mukerjee is $61$ the only non-Chen prime dividing both $3^n+3$ and $2^n-3$?